# Tropic Escape lost game

Tags: ios

My son and I both play Tropic Escape. He connected to Game Center on iPod Touch and it replaced my game on my iPad with his iPod Touch account. Is there a way I can get my account back?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, with games like this, the answer is typically no - at least not by yourself.

The best course of action would be to contact the developers of the game (Zynga). In games like this, it is very server-heavy, so they may be able to restore your progress from your profile that they have saved somewhere.